# Reset sum after withdrawal in rails marketplace app- now- sum funds in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a basic rails marketplace app where users can sell items.

After they sell items, they accumulate funds and are shown a $ amount. They then have the option to "cash out". As site admin, I will initiate a bank transfer or mail a check.

I want to be able to reset this $ amount to 0 after the cash out. I haven't been able to get it to work.

UPDATE: So, I am able to reset my funds variable to 0 after the withdrawal is completed. I had funds as an instance variable defined as `@funds = Order.where(seller: current_user).sum(:amount)` instead of storing in the database.

NOW: my question is, how do I define my funds variable in my model/controller so it will update the database as orders are placed? in other words how do I get similar behavior to `@funds = Order.where(seller: current_user).sum(:amount)`
except have it reflect in my database? Funds is a column in my users database

My withdrawals controller (updated):

```
def create       
@funds = current_user.funds
@withdrawal = Withdrawal.new(withdrawal_params)
@withdrawal.user_id = current_user.id
current_user.funds = 0
current_user.save





class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :listings
has_many :sales, class_name: "Order", foreign_key: "seller_id"
has_many :purchases, class_name: "Order", foreign_key: "buyer_id"
has_many :withdrawals
   end

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :listing
    belongs_to :buyer, class_name: "User"
    belongs_to :seller, class_name: "User"
end

class Withdrawal < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :buyer, class_name: "User"
    belongs_to :seller, class_name: "User"  
end
```

Comment: are you saving current_users's attributes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to save `current_user` after updating the funds or the update will not be persisted in the database. Either call save:

```
current_user.funds = 0
current_user.save
```

Or use `update_attributes`:

```
current_user.update_attributes(funds: 0)
```

Comment: Update your question with your model definitions and I can probably provide a better answer.